# Javascript - Predefined color gradient

Tags: javascript

I want to have a gradient between these 5 colors - FFCDB2, FFB4A2, E5989B, B5838D, 6D6875.

What I have currently cycles trough all colours

```js
function HSVtoRGB(h, s, v) {
    var r, g, b, i, f, p, q, t;
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        s = h.s, v = h.v, h = h.h;
    }
    i = Math.floor(h * 6);
    f = h * 6 - i;
    p = v * (1 - s);
    q = v * (1 - f * s);
    t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s);
    switch (i % 6) {
        case 0: r = v, g = t, b = p; break;
        case 1: r = q, g = v, b = p; break;
        case 2: r = p, g = v, b = t; break;
        case 3: r = p, g = q, b = v; break;
        case 4: r = t, g = p, b = v; break;
        case 5: r = v, g = p, b = q; break;
    }
    return {
        r: Math.round(r * 255),
        g: Math.round(g * 255),
        b: Math.round(b * 255)
    };
}

tickcount = Global.Tickcount();
colors = HSVtoRGB(tickcount % 350 / 350, 1, 1, 1, 255);

Render.GradientRect(watermark_x, 37, watermark_y, 2, 1, [colors.g, colors.b, colors.r, 255], [colors.r, colors.g, colors.b, 255]);
```

Comment: You will need to be more specific on your libraries, as `gradientrect` isn't standard javascript.

Comment: gradient rect is a  gradient rectangle  
Syntax Render.GradientRect( x, y, w, h, dir, [ col1 ], [ col2 ] );
Description Draws a gradient rectangle with the given position, size, and RGBA color.
Parameters x, y, w, h, dir, [ col1 ], [ col2 ]
Return values Returns true on success or false on failure.
dir argument stands for direction and 0 is vertical while 1 is horizontal
function drawGradient()
{
    Render.GradientRect( 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, [ 255, 0, 0, 255 ], [ 255, 255, 255, 255 ]);
    Render.GradientRect( 210, 100, 100, 100, 1, [ 255, 0, 0, 255 ], [ 255, 255, 255, 255 ]);
}